# Delete temporary locked files

Tags: java, file, locking

At some point of my process i have to delete a specific file, because the file is used as "flag" that something was corrupted (Part of a Backup Logic).

Sometimes the file is locked by a virus scanner or anything else, but this lock is temporary. In any case the specific file has to be deleted, otherwise the next process may be broken.
I also thought about creating a second file flag that the first flag is corrupt, but in the end you could create hundreds of flags, so this is not a solution.

I tried to delete the file wihtin a loop and keep waiting for some millis, before trying to fire the next delete command.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (FileUtils.deleteQuietly(file)) {
            break;
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            break;
        }
    }
```

1. Do you see a Utility class out there this scenario is already
   implemented?
2. How do you handle create/delete commands if a virus scanner is locking you files?

Comment: You might have a look at the file [lock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html)ing mechanism using [a file channel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html)

Comment: In the end you have the same problem in getting a lock for a temporary locked file.

Comment: If it's **really** temporary you might use `lock()` as this is a blocking call and will only return if you got the lock. But it might be dangerous. As you did not explain the flow of your code (when the temporary file is created, is it the same instance which also delete the file) it's hard to make a good proposal.